# React IIS Hosting ( DOM does not get refreshed)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, iis-8

working on a React Application, which has 4 pages and if I run locally, routing works fine and all different pages gets rendered properly with routing... However, this is not the case with IIS.

Created a dist folder and mapped dist directory on IIS. when I navigate, second page gets loaded and * when I move to different pages, dom does not get clear... all pages gets rendered beneath each other*

Not sure what I am missing.. please advise.

**RouteConfig.js**

```
class RouteConfig extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
   <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={A} />
    <Route path="/b" component={B} />
    <Route path="/c" component={C} />
  </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
   )
};
}
```

**App.js
This is my first page... which has link... when user click on link... we navigate to component a**

```
class RouteConfig extends Component{
  render(){
       return (
    <div> <Link to="/a" </div>
   );
}
```

**Index.js**

```
render(
 <RouteConfig>
   <App />
 </RouteConfig>

);
```

Comment: It can be problem with Routing.. You need to set `exact="true"` for each route

Comment: @ma_dev_15, when added exact="true" for each route, deployed and verified, I do not see any page at all... just blank white page

Comment: you can please share the link of the repo. Did you set any default route?
I mean Route with `path="/"`

Comment: App.js must get loaded first

Comment: Share your repo

Answer (score 1):

You should post the code from your `react-router` as it sounds like a router problem.

If that is the issue, you should be able to solve it using `exact`:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Take a look at the router examples here [React Training -React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)